# Check whether a div exists and redirect if not

Tags: javascript, html

How do I check whether a certain `div` exist on my page and if not, redirect the visitor to another page?

Comment: Does that DIV have a `id` attribute?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to be able to check if the element exists and do the redirect.

Assuming the div has an id (e.g. div id="elementId") you can simply do:

```
if (!document.getElementById("elementId")) {
    window.location.href = "redirectpage.html";
}
```

If you are using jQuery, the following would be the solution:

```
if ($("#elementId").length === 0){
    window.location.href = "redirectpage.html";
}
```

**Addition:**

If you need to check the content of divs for a specific word (as I think that is what you are now asking) you can do this (jQuery):

```
$("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("copyright") >= 0)) {
        window.location.href = "redirectpage.html";
    }
});​
```

Comment: You can simply use `location` instead of `window.location` ;)

Comment: Yes, you can :) but you could have a local variable "location" within the same scope, that would override the global location variable. That's why I tend to use the "window." prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery you can check it like this:

<del>if ($("#divToCheck")){
      // div exists
    } else {
      // OOPS div missing
    }</del>

or

```
if ($("#divToCheck").length > 0){
  // div exists
} else {
  // OOPS div missing
}
```

or

```
if ($("#divToCheck")[0]) {
  // div exists
} else {
  // OOPS div missing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What differenciate this particular div from others on the page ?

If it has an ID, you can to this with document.getElementById:

```
var div = document.getElementById('the-id-of-the-div');
if (!div) {
    location = '/the-ohter-page.html';
}
```

You can also check the content of the div:

```
var div = document.getElementById('the-id-of-the-div');
var html = div.innerHTML;

// check that div contains the word "something"
if (!/something/.test(html)) {
    location = '/the-ohter-page.html';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that

```
if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
    // do something here
}
```

Read more here: http://jquery.com/

Edit: Fixed the error pointed out in the comment below. Sorry, busy day at work and got too trigger happy.

Comment: `$("#mydiv")` always returns an object and always evaluate to true

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but do you know how can check the content of the div for example if the div contains the word [copyright] it redirect the visitors to another page . Thank you