# Page refresh, javascript not running

Tags: javascript, html

I'm brand new to web programming, never played with it past a basic level and have started a small graphing project with HTML5 canvas. While beginning to build a reallu basic page I've ran into some HTML/JS stuff that's quite simple but I for the life of me cant figure out what's wrong. It wont run for some reason.

I was originally hosting the JS in an external file but in the same directory such as

```
<script src="numValues.js"></script>
```

Is this correct or best practice?

My Markup/JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <META charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>EZgraph | Pie Chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
 function addFields()
 {
    var numValues = document.getElementById("numValues").value;

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    while(container.HasChildNodes())
    {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }

    for (i=0; i < numValues; i++)
    {
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("value " + (i+1)));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "number";
                input.name = "Value" + i;
                container.appendChild(input);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
 }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="inputCountText"></div>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return addFields()">
            <input type="number" id="numValues" required>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Are there any good IDE's/setups for this kind of work on a Mac? I'm currently using SublimeText.

Comment: It's generally best practice to keep the JavaScript code in a separate file.  For really simple things it's not always worth the overhead, but as the code grows in complexity it's best to separate it.  Was that the only question?  The title implies something else is wrong, but you didn't mention it.

Comment: Yeah, the code looks fine but doesn't run.
I input to the text field, hit submit and the page does nothing. 

I'm assuming my lack of experience meant I was overlooking something silly, but I've been over it and over it and can't find a mistake.


I was originally, but for the purposes of simplicity I embedded it. When refernceing external JS, should I use something such as my first code sample?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't run", what *does* it do?  The JavaScript code definitely executes when the page loads (unless JavaScript is disabled in the browser, which is possible).  Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?  Browsers come with very useful debugging tools these days, such as FireBug or Chrome developer tools.  There could be an error on the browser console that you're just not looking at.  Or maybe a logical error in the code that you can find by stepping through in a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see my comment on your own answer.
Also, you should always check if you get what you need:

```
 function addFields()
 {
    var returnValue = false;
    var numValues = document.getElementById("numValues").value;
    if (numValues.length != 0)
    {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        if (container.length != 0)
        {

            while (container.hasChildNodes())
            {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
            {
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("value " + (i+1)));
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                if (input.length > 0)
                {
                    input.type = "number";
                    input.name = "Value" + i;
                    container.appendChild(input);
                    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    returnValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
 }
```

Comment: I see what you mean in your above comment. 

A question though, your second nested if statement checking container.length, why is this here? containter is an empty div with and ID to hold the generated fields, surely it will always be 0 initially?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204155/check-whether-a-div-exists-and-redirect-if-not

Answer (score 2):

finally found my problem, it was syntax

`container.HasChildNodes()`

should be

```
container.hasChildNodes()
```

the page shows the generated fields for an instant but they then dissapear? Why is this?

Comment: because the page was submitted. you should `return false` if you do not want the page to submit.

Comment: This is the kind of info I'm missing on the subject, didn't even realize this was a problem that existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the console of the Browser? Safari is actually not too bad for debugging. The console should show you where the error is.

I usually use something like the following to test which commands were executed.

```
console.log('Step 1');
```